# How to find default route table id of a specific subnet?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to add a route to the default route table of a specific subnet.
I know how to add a route to a table given its id, but how do I find the id of the route table that is associated with a specific subnet?
I tried the following:

```
data "aws_route_table" "rt" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.terra1_subnet.id
}

resource "aws_route" "r" {
  route_table_id         = data.aws_route_table.rt.id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.terra1_igw.id
}
```

However I am getting "query returned no results."

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody needs it:

In my code I am creating a VCP, so here I am using data to query the main root table that is created along with the VPC and for that I am filtering the parameter association.main. Every VPC has a default root table that has its main parameter set as yes. Looking the documentation, you can find how to reference that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeRouteTables.html

```
data "aws_route_table" "main" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.this.id
  filter {
    name = "association.main"
    values = ["true"]
  }
}
resource "aws_ec2_tag" "main-route-table" {
  resource_id = data.aws_route_table.main.id
  key = "Name"
  value = "${local.vpc_name}-default-root-table"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following & it works for me.

```
data "aws_route_table" "main" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["YOUR-ROUTE-TABLE-NAME"]
  }
}

output "route_table_id" {
  value = data.aws_route_table.main.id
}

resource "aws_route" "r" {
  route_table_id         = data.aws_route_table.main.id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.terra1_igw.id
}
```

OR

```
## Obtain through associated subnet with data sources
data "aws_subnet" "private" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = [YOUR-SUBNET-NAME"]
  }
}

data "aws_route_table" "rt" {
  subnet_id = data.aws_subnet.private.id
}

output "route_table_id" {
  value = data.aws_route_table.rt.id
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!
It works well when I explicitly associate a routing table with the subnet, but not with the default routing table of the subnet. It is as if Terraform doesn't consider the default routing table as a routing table when trying to get the information through the data source.

Comment: np - My understanding is that data sources can only refer to constant values already known. In your data source block subnet_id = aws_subnet.terra1_subnet.id ... that seems incorrect because it referring to a resources output. Maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: It seems that when creating public subnets, terraform will automatically create a route table but not associate it with the internet gateway. This association can be specified manually if terraform can find the route table ID- so how does terraform get the id of an _implicitly_ generated route table?